# Discrete Math, How many five decimal digits are there that have exactly 3 9s

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Counting 2:

How many strings of five decimal digits are there that have exactly 3 9s?

Here is what I did:

XXXXX - representing the 5 digits
11199 - the 1 represent that I have one option, the 9s go there, and the 9 is how many numbers I can pick from excluding 9 (0-9).
My answer is 81, is this right?

Comment: No.  THere is nothing that says the three $9$ must all go in the last three positions.

Comment: What you haven't taken into account is that the three $9$s can appear in any position.  There are ${5\choose 3}$ ways to pick the positions and then there are $9\times 9$ ways to pick the remaining two numbers from $0$-$8$ (not (0-9) as you wrote).  This gives you RyRy the Fly Guy's answer.

Comment: If you find the answer below satisfactory, then please close your inquiry by clicking the green check mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Count the combinations of strings of $5$ digits that contain $3$ nines. In other words, among the $5$ positions where a nine can appear, how many unique combinations of three are there? This is $5 \choose 3$. Then, for each such string, count the number of permutations of nine digits $0,1,2,...,8$ that go in the remaining two positions. This would be $9 \cdot 9$ because one of $9$ digits can go in either position. By the general counting principle we have

$$ {5 \choose 3} \cdot 9 \cdot 9 = \frac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot 9 \cdot 9 = \frac{5 \cdot 4}{2} \cdot 9 \cdot 9 = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 = 810 $$

Comment: Can a five digit number start with $0$?

Comment: fleablood, the OP is concerned with valid strings and not necessarily a representation of a number, so in this case a five digit string can indeed start with a $0$. If the OP is concerned with valid number representations, then he or she should update/clarify the question.

Comment: So they are.  So they are.  And so they should.

Comment: haha yes i just finished updating my post because i realized my mistake

Answer (score 0):

BTW you asked for *strings*, and as such RyRy the Fly Guy has correctly answered.

But *if* you want $5$ digit *numbers* so that the first digit can not be $0$ you must do something else.

I think the easiest way is to calculate the total strings and subtract the numbers that start with $0$.  If the first position is $0$ there are ${4\choose 3}=4$ ways to choose the positions of the three $9$s.  There are $9$ values for the last remaining position so that is $4\times 9=36$ ways to have a string with exactly $3$ nines beginning with $0$ and therefore $810-36 = 774$ ways to have five digit numbers with exactly $3$ nines.

Alternatively.  YOu can add the numbers of way to do this if the first digit is $9$ and the numbers of ways to do this if the first digit isn't $9$.  If the first digit is $9$ there are $8$ choices for the first digit.   ${4\choose 3}=4$ ways to choose the positions of the three $9$s.  ANd there are $9$ choices for the last remaining position.  This is $8\times 4 \times 9 = 288$ ways to have a five digit number that does not begin with $0$ or $9$ and has $3$ digits.

If the first digit *is* $9$ then there are ${4\choose 2} = \frac{4\cdot 3}2 = 6$ choices of positions for the other two $9$s.  Then the remaining two positions can be filled with anything from 0-8 so there are $9\times 9$ ways to fill those.  So $6\times 9\times 9 = 486$ ways to have a five digit number with three $9$s beginning with a $9$.

There there are $288 + 486=774 $ ways.